# Can anyone help me move data from an Axios JSON response to a plot points on a Chart js line chart?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I am working on building a React app that contains a line chart representing the timeline of data recordings from a certain point in time to present day. I am using the JS library Chart js. Specifically the 'react-chartjs-2' plugin. I am using the '/historical/all' path of the following API:

[https://corona.lmao.ninja/docs/?urls.primaryName=version%202.0.0#/][1]

I am successfully retrieving a response from the Axios GET request. But the structuring of the JSON being sent back to me is confusing me when it comes to the implementation I have been following to build the application. I have a lot of the scaffolding in place, but I am struggling to get the data from GET request function to the line chart.

The data is being sent in the following structure:

```
{
    "cases": {
        "3/21/20": 304507,
        "3/22/20": 336953,
        "3/23/20": 378231,
        "3/24/20": 418041,
        "3/25/20": 467653,
        "3/26/20": 529591,
        "3/27/20": 593291,
        "3/28/20": 660693,
        "3/29/20": 720140,
        "3/30/20": 782389,
        "3/31/20": 857487,
        "4/1/20": 932605,
        "4/2/20": 1013466,
        "4/3/20": 1095917,
        "4/4/20": 1176060,
        "4/5/20": 1249754,
        "4/6/20": 1321481,
        "4/7/20": 1396476,
        "4/8/20": 1480202,
        "4/9/20": 1565278,
        "4/10/20": 1657526,
        "4/11/20": 1735650,
        "4/12/20": 1834721,
        "4/13/20": 1904838,
        "4/14/20": 1976191,
        "4/15/20": 2056054,
        "4/16/20": 2152437,
        "4/17/20": 2240190,
        "4/18/20": 2317758,
        "4/19/20": 2401378
    },
    "deaths": {
        "3/21/20": 12973,
        "3/22/20": 14651,
        "3/23/20": 16505,
        "3/24/20": 18625,
        "3/25/20": 21181,
        "3/26/20": 23970,
        "3/27/20": 27198,
        "3/28/20": 30652,
        "3/29/20": 33925,
        "3/30/20": 37582,
        "3/31/20": 42107,
        "4/1/20": 47180,
        "4/2/20": 52983,
        "4/3/20": 58787,
        "4/4/20": 64606,
        "4/5/20": 69374,
        "4/6/20": 74565,
        "4/7/20": 81937,
        "4/8/20": 88338,
        "4/9/20": 95521,
        "4/10/20": 102525,
        "4/11/20": 108502,
        "4/12/20": 114090,
        "4/13/20": 119481,
        "4/14/20": 125983,
        "4/15/20": 134176,
        "4/16/20": 143800,
        "4/17/20": 153821,
        "4/18/20": 159509,
        "4/19/20": 165043
    },
    "recovered": {
        "3/21/20": 91682,
        "3/22/20": 97889,
        "3/23/20": 98341,
        "3/24/20": 107890,
        "3/25/20": 113604,
        "3/26/20": 121966,
        "3/27/20": 130659,
        "3/28/20": 138949,
        "3/29/20": 148616,
        "3/30/20": 164100,
        "3/31/20": 176442,
        "4/1/20": 191853,
        "4/2/20": 208528,
        "4/3/20": 223621,
        "4/4/20": 243575,
        "4/5/20": 257000,
        "4/6/20": 273259,
        "4/7/20": 296263,
        "4/8/20": 324507,
        "4/9/20": 348813,
        "4/10/20": 370241,
        "4/11/20": 395521,
        "4/12/20": 414599,
        "4/13/20": 440897,
        "4/14/20": 466051,
        "4/15/20": 502053,
        "4/16/20": 532409,
        "4/17/20": 557798,
        "4/18/20": 581355,
        "4/19/20": 612056
    }
}
```

I would like for each category (cases, deaths, recovered) to represent a line on the chart showing the progression over time, but I'm unsure how to handle it. With the intention being that the dates would be the X-axis and the points would be plotted in a different colored line for each.

Would anyone be able to help with this at all? I would greatly appreciate some guidance. Below are the two primary files corresponding to the Chart and API handling:

index.js

```
   export const fetchDailyData = async () => {



  try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/historical/all`);

      const labels = Object.keys(data.cases);
      const cases = labels.map((name) => data.cases[name]);
      const deaths = labels.map((name) => data.deaths[name]);
      const recovered = labels.map((name) => data.recovered[name]);

      return {labels, cases, deaths, recovered};





  } catch (error) {
    return error;

  }
}
```

Chart.jsx

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Line, Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { fetchDailyData } from '../../api';

import styles from './Chart.module.css';



const Chart = ({data: { labels, cases, deaths, recovered }}) => {
    const [dailyData, setDailyData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAPI = async () => {
            setDailyData(await fetchDailyData());
        }

        fetchAPI();
    }, []);





    const lineChart = (
        <Line data = {
            {
                labels,
                datasets: [{
                        data:cases,
                        label: 'Infected',
                        borderColor: '#3333ff',
                        fill: true,

                    }, {
                        data: deaths,
                        label: 'Deaths',
                        borderColor: 'red',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                        fill: true,
                    },
                    {
                        data: recovered,
                        label: 'Recovered',
                        borderColor: 'green',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
                        fill: true,
                    }],
            }
        }



        />
    );

    return ( 
        <div className = { styles.container }> 
            {lineChart}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Chart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete solution:

```
// Create the chartData state
const [chartData, setChartData] = useState();

// in your fetch function, convert the data to chartData
const labels = Object.keys(data.cases);
const cases = labels.map((name) => data.cases[name]);
const deaths = labels.map((name) => data.deaths[name]);
const recovered = labels.map((name) => data.recovered[name]);
setChartData({
    labels,
    datasets: [{
        data: cases,
        label: 'Infected',
        borderColor: '#3333ff',
        fill: true
    }, {
        data: deaths,
        label: 'Deaths',
        borderColor: 'red',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        fill: true
    }, {
        data: recovered,
        label: 'Recovered',
        borderColor: 'green',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
        fill: true
    }]
})

// Now render your chart (but make sure chartData exists)
return ( 
    <div className = { styles.container }> 
        {chartData &&
            <Line data={chartData} />
        }
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First extract the x labels:

```
const labels = Object.keys(dailyData.cases);
```

Then extract the y values for each serie:

```
const cases = Object.keys(dailyData.cases).map((name) => dailyData.cases[name]);
const deaths = Object.keys(dailyData.deaths).map((name) => dailyData.deaths[name]);
const recovered = Object.keys(dailyData.recovered).map((name) => dailyData.recovered[name]);
```

Then assemble everything into a chart js object:

```
<Line data = {
    labels,
    datasets: [{
        data: cases,
        label: 'Infected',
        borderColor: '#3333ff',
        fill: true
      }, {
         data: deaths,
         label: 'Deaths',
         borderColor: 'red',
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
         fill: true
       }, {
         data: recovered,
         label: 'Recovered',
         borderColor: 'green',
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
         fill: true
       }]
     }    
/>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! Does the extraction of x and y values need to be done in the fetchDailyData() function?

Comment: I think you should do it in fetch, and save the 4 const (labels, cases, deaths and recovered)  to state like this:   `const [labels, setLabels] = useStae([]);` ...

Comment: Gotcha! When you referenced dailyData in the dot notation, would that be changed to the 'data' object in index.js? A reference to dailyData breaks

Comment: dailyData is indeed the data object, and you don't need to save it to state anymore because you're converting it right away in your fetch function

Comment: Ahh okay gotcha! So is returning those 4 const out of fetchDailyData() as 

return {labels, cases, deaths, recovered};

the proper return statement?

Comment: when I attempt to use the labels variable, I get labels.slice is not a function error

Comment: How did you initialize labels?

Comment: It's the const [labels, setLabels] = useState([])];

Comment: Do I need to initialize all those variables in Chart.jsx?

Comment: That's correct, where do you have this slice error?

Comment: The area just under the <Line data ={

When I try to set the labels of the chart

Comment: I console logged the label variable and it returns null

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me again! I really appreciate it. All the json I've dealt with before has not confused me this much. Or at least taking it to another component.

When I create the 4 variables, should Object be my response object ('data') and is should dailyData be changed? It throws an undefined error

Comment: Thanks so much! Everything seems to be working as intended in index.js. Do you know how I can bring the constants over to Chart.jsx? I tried to return them as an object, but it did not work. i get undefined for those 4 constants in Chart.jsx

Comment: Please look at my second answer, this is a fully working solution (I tested it)

Comment: Gotcha! When you perform the labels and data extraction and map to an array, is that done in the same file as the Chart? Or do you declare those variables in both Chart. jsx and index.js?

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to convert the raw data to chart data inside your Chart.jsx component, usually this is done just after you fetch the data from the API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212166/discussion-between-kortney-stinson-and-hermitcrab).